# How to conditionally include one of two files in a .war package with Buildr?

Tags: java, war, buildr

We're using Buildr to package an application as a [.war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28Sun_file_format%29) file. To streamline the automated deployment process further, I'd like to conditionally select one of these two files (from the directory `src/main/resources`)...

- `database-hsql.properties`
- `database-postgres.properties`

...and have it included in the resulting .war with the name `database.properties`. (In the same place inside the WAR, namely `WEB-INF/classes/`, where files from `src/main/resources` now end up.)

Any simple way to do this? Any approach would be fine — e.g. parameterising "package" (somehow) or defining two different tasks/targets (I'm not sure of the terminology) such as "package-hsql" & "package-pgsql" — as long as it works and is simple enough.

Relevant bits of `buildfile`:

```
load 'dependencies' 
require 'buildr/hibernate'

desc "..."
define "foo" do

  project.version = VERSION_NUMBER
  project.group = GROUP
  manifest["Implementation-Vendor"] = COPYRIGHT
  compile.with WICKET,GUAVA,GSON, ... [many more libs]
  test.with MOCKITO
  resources

  test.compile.with SERVLET,_('src/main/webapp'),_('src/main/resources')
  package(:war).with(:libs=> [WICKET,GUAVA,GSON, ... ])

end
```

**Bonus question**: how to execute an arbitrary shell command (I'd use something involving e.g. `>>` or `sed`) in each of the two cases to make changes to another config file? (I'd also want to "inject" some db settings to `applicationContext.xml` from another file; this would be preferable to keeping two copies of that file in VCS with mostly identical content.)

Sorry if this is too basic; I'm a total newbie with Buildr, and don't really know Ruby. (And yes, it's not an optimal situation to be using a tool that no current team member is proficient with...) If anything needs clarifying, please point it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to parameterize a buildr build is with environment variables.  So for instance you might design your build to be executed like so:

```
$ buildr package DATABASE=postgres
```

In your buildfile you might then have:

```
ENV['DATABASE'] ||= 'hsql' # this line makes the default 'hsql'

define "foo" do
  # the rest of the definition

  resources.enhance do
    cp _(:source, :main, :resources, "database-#{ENV['DATABASE']}.properties"), _(:target, :resources, "database.properties")
  end
end
```

This is the simplest solution; one thing you might consider a drawback is that it will copy the two `database-*.properties` files in addition to the `database.properties` file that you'll actually use.  If that's a problem it could be worked around at the cost of some more complexity.

**Bonus answer**:  You can execute an arbitrary shell command using `system`.  E.g., at the cost of subshelling I could have implemented the above as:

```
resources.enhance do
  system("cp '#{_(:source, :main, :resources, "database-#{ENV['DATABASE']}.properties")}' '#{_(:target, :resources, "database.properties")}'")
end
```

If you are wanting to inject properties into a configuration file, you might want to look at Buildr's [filter](http://buildr.apache.org/building.html#resources) mechanism.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I got it working using the "cp" approach. (Right now I'm in a bit of a hurry, but later on the bonus case (applicationContext.xml) really should be cleaned up, perhaps with the filter mechanism you mention...)